# Download media file from twilio, using the media URI

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, twilio

I have been having issues with downloading [media from the media uri](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media) provided on the mms messages.

```
val url = https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xx/Messages/xx/Media/xx
```

the media url provided is in the above structure,

```
new URL(url) #> new File("file.png") !! //this fails, due to multiple redirects
```

When I open the URI in browser the redirect ends up in

```
http://media.twiliocdn.com.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/xx/xx
```

> 1st url -> 2nd url -> above url ;so,all in all 2 redirects

And if I try the snippet posted above with the new url, it works. I am sure its because of the multiple redirects, the snippet didnt work in the first place.

Been using **play framework** with **scala**, can I get any source example to download the file. Any help or pointers is appreciated. Tried various examples but still could not solve the issue.

Some findings =>
[Accessing Twilio MMS images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383166/accessing-twilio-mms-images)

anything similar for scala?

**Update:** @millhouse

```
def fileDownloader(urls: String, location: String) = {

    import play.api.Play.current
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    // Make the request
    val futureResponse: Future[(WSResponseHeaders, Enumerator[Array[Byte]])] =
      WS.url(urls).withFollowRedirects(true).getStream()

    futureResponse.flatMap {
      case (headers, body) =>
        val file = new File(location)
        val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)

        // The iteratee that writes to the output stream
        val iteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { bytes =>
          outputStream.write(bytes)
        }

        // Feed the body into the iteratee
        (body |>>> iteratee).andThen {
          case result =>
            // Close the output stream whether there was an error or not
            outputStream.close()
            // Get the result or rethrow the error
            result.get
        }.map(_ => file)
    }
  }
```

This is the approach I had been using till now(works), as explained in the play docs. But I needed a **sync approach**, meaning I would need to carry out **another step** **on successful file download**. Sorry, for not clarifying out ahead.

Update 2 : Solved in this manner,

```
        def fileDownloader(urls: String, location: String) = {

                    import play.api.Play.current
                    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

                    // Make the request
                    val futureResponse: Future[(WSResponseHeaders, Enumerator[Array[Byte]])] =
                      WS.url(urls).withFollowRedirects(true).getStream()

                     val downloadedFile: Future[File] = futureResponse.flatMap {
                      case (headers, body) =>
                        val file = new File(location)
                        val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)

                        // The iteratee that writes to the output stream
                        val iteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { bytes =>
                          outputStream.write(bytes)
                        }

                        // Feed the body into the iteratee
                        (body |>>> iteratee).andThen {
                          case result =>
                            // Close the output stream whether there was an error or not
                            outputStream.close()
                            // Get the result or rethrow the error
                            result.get
                        }.map(_ => file)
                    }
    downloadedFile.map{ fileIn =>
              //things needed to do
}
                  }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the Twilio MMS API but it should be very straightforward to get the Play Framework HTTP client to follow redirects, using the [documented option](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Request-with-follow-redirects) to the client:

```
val url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xx/Messages/xx/Media/xx"

ws.url(url).withFollowRedirects(true).get().map { response =>
  val theBytes:Array[Byte] = response.bodyAsBytes // Play 2.4 and lower
  // ... save it  
}
```

Note that the above code works for Play 2.4.x and lower; [the `bodyAsBytes` method of `WSResponse` returns an `Array[Byte]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse). If you're on the current cutting-edge and using [Play 2.5.x, `bodyAsBytes`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse) gives you an [Akka `ByteString`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.4/index.html#akka.util.ByteString) with lots of nice functional methods, but you probably just want to call `toArray` on it if all you want is to store the data:

```
ws.url(url).withFollowRedirects(true).get().map { response =>
  val theBytes:Array[Byte] = response.bodyAsBytes.toArray // Play 2.5
  // ... save it  
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But, I can't seem to find `bodyAsBytes` method relating/applicable to the ws response. Am I missing any imports or .... using 2.3.8 btw

Comment: Thanks for your help @millhouse! If you'd like a thank you t-shirt from Twilio send an email to mspeir@twilio.com.